# Creating overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, z-index

I'm trying to display a span overlapping a canvas element along the canvas' left border.

```
<!doctype html />
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Z-Index</title>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="timeline_wrapper"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', 500);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', 500);
        canvas.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 8px; z-index: 0;');
        document.getElementById("timeline_wrapper").appendChild(canvas);

        // draw back button
        var back = document.createElement('div');
        back.setAttribute('width', 50);
        back.setAttribute('height', 500);
        back.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #336699; position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 8px; z-index: 1');
        document.getElementById("timeline_wrapper").appendChild(back);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No matter what I've tried, the back element doesn't show up at all. 
Apart from the back element being positioned at 50, 50 from top, left, does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers,
Joshua

Comment: Why is the canvas fixed and the span positioned absolute. 336699 is not a valid color. Prepend a '#'.

Comment: @edwin: Changed the fixed to absolute, and prepended #. No luck, updating question to reflect ruled out causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<!doctype html /> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Z-Index</title>    
  </head> 

  <body> 
    <div id="timeline_wrapper"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid; position: fixed; top: 8px; left: 8px; z-index: 0; width: 500px; height: 500px;');
        document.getElementById("timeline_wrapper").appendChild(canvas);

        // draw back button
        var back = document.createElement('div');
        back.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: 336699; position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 8px; z-index: 1; width: 50px; height: 500px;');
        document.getElementById("timeline_wrapper").appendChild(back);

    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

(I moved the width and height into the css, it isn't a dom attribute)

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I'm trying to do. Moving width and height to css did the trick.

Comment: Is it only the div that doesn't have width and height dom attributes, or both the canvas and the div? I ask because the canvas itself always got drawn in my experiments.

Comment: In html5 (which I just noticed you are using) the canvas tag does have height and width attributes, although it is generally considered good practice to put those in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, my first guess is that the problem is because of the span tag. Spans are inline elements, which means they don't behave the same as block elements. Try using css to change the display property of the span to 'block', or simply use a div instead of a span.

Comment: I changed the question so it can be run by itself. I changed the span to a div, still no luck.